# Restoring rights for /var

Tags: permissions, login, root, chown

I accidentally ran

```
sudo chown www-data /var -R
```

Right after I ran

```
sudo chown root /var -R
```

To restore the correct ownership. However, I can no longer login. I'm still getting the full disk encryption password step, though not the one after that.

To fix the issue, I need to know where the owner should not be root, so I can change it back. I can still get to the root shell via recovery mode. Any pointers?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: That is not the command you ran. Why not? Cuz root owns var and you did not change anything. Please provide the result of `ls -l /`, specifically the line that contains /var/. Did you perhaps include -R in the command?

Comment: See if you can get to a tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 after it boots up.

Comment: Updated to be more accurate. I indeed did use the -R flag.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by setting the user and group of the `/var/lib/lightdm` directory back to `lightdm`.